# Drawing in complex number in Excel

Tags: excel, complex-numbers

I have some output numbers in complex shape and I want to draw them by Excel sheet for the imaginary part only with another parameter.
Can anybody help?

here is some example of the data;
complex  ( 0.99986847902877907     ,  1.1969213425916347E-002)
complex ( 0.99993268865903517     ,  9.2103081512170948E-003)
complex ( 0.99995225406590338     ,  8.1829966554218120E-003)
complex ( 0.99996184275286770     ,  7.5981322777361983E-003)
complex ( 0.99996736415713050     ,  7.2098480666749100E-003)
complex ( 0.99997080157607610     ,  6.9298204405398908E-003)
complex ( 0.99997302559596635     ,  6.7169474800091141E-003)
complex ( 0.99997448140595457     ,  6.5490571546403392E-003)
complex ( 0.99997542081718938     ,  6.4129719837361359E-003)
complex ( 0.99997599697773831     ,  6.3003011472539941E-003)
complex ( 0.99997630831216933     ,  6.2054176280065525E-003)
complex ( 0.99997642089449401     ,  6.1243919081143145E-003)
complex ( 0.99997638068261452     ,  6.0543889299894786E-003)
complex ( 0.99997622059940150     ,  5.9933075435334012E-003)
complex ( 0.99997596482582596     ,  5.9395549697247776E-003)
complex ( 0.99997563150673174     ,  5.8919003296796970E-003)
complex ( 0.99997523451330173     ,  5.8493764619808953E-003)
complex ( 0.99997478462415557     ,  5.8112122991709134E-003)
complex ( 0.99997429033668661     ,  5.7767851841812289E-003)
complex ( 0.99997375843669056     ,  5.7455865476157067E-003)
complex ( 0.99997319440609989     ,  5.7171967479152036E-003)
complex ( 0.99997260271994126     ,  5.6912663275716507E-003)
complex ( 0.99997198706600188     ,  5.6675018439141748E-003)

and I want to draw the imaginary part only in Y-axis with this data;
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide an example of what you are working on?

Comment: here is some example of the data;